# Conversion of PDF file to Excel in R

Tags: r, excel, pdf

I want to convert a pdf (which is of 2 pages) into excel. The pdf consists of two table balance sheet and profit and loss table for a company. Now I got this online code (in R) which works perfectly, but from the 2 pages, it is only converting the 2nd page not the first. I searched everywhere and I also tried different solutions, but not working. As there are a lot of such files the online conversion tools are also too costly. Can anyone please help me with this. If it can convert both the pages at once it will be great.

```
library("pdftools")
tx1<-pdf_text("C:/Users/Snehal Salaskar/Desktop/Companies/CanFin/2013-14.pdf")
tx3<-strsplit(tx1,"\n")
lapply(tx3, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'Profit.csv'  , sep=',' ))
```

I want it to convert all the 2 pages at once

Comment: If the data isn't personal, you will be better off uploading the data online and sharing the link e.g. with https://www.filedropper.com/. Otherwise, if the data is small `dput` can work to get a copy of the data via the clipboard. Not suitable for large objects though. Possibly `dput(tx3)[[1]]`, `dput(tx3)[[2]]`,.. may work

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/2013-14. This is the file dput won't work as the data is large.

Comment: if I do this dput(tx3)[[1]], dput(tx3)[[2]] it is saying unexpected ',' as there are only two objects in the list this might work but its giving this error.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at the pdf, it looks like quite a bit of work is required to format it in to a nice table. If you just want to capture the outputs to a file, the issue is you were saving to the same file name twice

You can either save to two files, or use `append=TRUE` to save them both to one file e.g.

```
# save to two files
lapply(seq_along(tx3), function(i){
  write.table( data.frame(tx3[[i]]), sprintf('Profit_%s.csv', i), sep=',' )
}) 

# save to single file with append=TRUE adding on the data
lapply(seq_along(tx3), function(i){
  write.table( data.frame(tx3[[i]]), sprintf('Profit.csv', i), sep=',' ,
               append = TRUE)
})
```

I prefer to use the indexes with `seq_along` than the object itself in the `lapply` as it then gives me an identifier number as well as the object, to add to the filename

Comment: Okay so what I did was putting append = true in my previous code itself and it was printing both the lists in one file, though lots of editing is done after conversion. I will try this one as well and check. Thank you for the help, will try this.